# How to add software license to a C++ project in Netbeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I can see a "License Headers" section in the Properties dialog for a Java Project.

But i dont see similar section to add "License Header" section for a C++ project.

how can i add it?

Comment: Does this help ?  https://netbeans.org/projects/cnd/lists/users/archive/2011-03/message/160 or this ? http://jdevel.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/netbeans-source-files-license-header-by-project/

Comment: thanks. it says to modify the license template, save it and create new files from this template. i saved the template, didn't edit it, now how to choose template when creating a new header file? no such option in the 'New File' dialog :(